# private method in controller to get object

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

```
module Api  
   class ApiController < ApplicationController

    before_filter :authenticate        
    private
      def authenticate
        #check if GET parameter
        return true if @user = User.find_by_token(params[:token])

        #check if token in header
        authenticate_or_request_with_http_token do |token, options|
           @user = User.find_by_token(token)
        end      
      end      
  end
end

module Api
  module V1
    class AdvertisementImagesController < ApiController

      def index
        @images = images
      end

      def create
        if images.create :remote_image_url=>params[:image][:remote_image_url] 
          return render :nothing => true, :status=>201
        else
          return render :nothing => true, :status=>500
        end

     private
      def images
        @user.advertisements.find(params[:advertisement_id]).images  
      end
```

throws

```
undefined local variable or method `images' for #<Api::V1::AdvertisementImagesController:0xb2d558d8>
```

If i put the Method in the ApiController, then it is working.

```
#in ApiControler
private        
  def images
    @user.advertisements.find(params[:advertisement_id]).images  
  end
```

if i put the method in the images_controller, then its giving an error.

What is the Problem?

Comment: Is the `objec` in `create` a typo? What line specifically throws the error?

Comment: @images = object - at index method. also no difference if i rename that method

Comment: Rename as in naming the method "ohai" or something? `object` *is* a method used across some of the Rails API. Also, it's unclear from your indentation where `object` is actually defined: is it in the controller class?

Comment: It's unclear where `object` is defined: where is it defined? I.e., what is its scope?

Comment: Please include the code in question, and indent consistently so we can tell where it's actually defined.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22607/discussion-between-huan-son-and-dave-newton)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to put an end to your method `create`. That is why ruby gets confused.

Comment: youre right. was super confusing with all these ends of module etc. thanks! appreciated!

Comment: I am sorry I did not understand this comment